# Asp.NET MVC 4 User once logs in, and click on browser back to login page(without logging out) either don't allow him or redirect to home page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a project using Asp.NET MVC4.

I've a situation where once a user logs in and he clicks on the browser back button and logs in again I get the error  **The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "", but the current user is "xxxxxx".**

I also found this solution on the net  [Link](http://www.nedoweb.com/Blog/tabid/60/EntryId/23/The-provided-anti-forgery-token-was-meant-for-user-but-the-current-user-is-myUsername.aspx) , but didn't help.

**Any solutions???**

Answer (score 1):

In your HttpPost function, the first thing you should do is check if the User is Authenticated. If they are already Authenticated, then redirect them to a page, this will stop the Authentication process from issuing any more cookies.

Comment: When antiforgery token is no longer valid the post method will not be called anymore. Your suggested solution will not work.

Comment: There's no reason why the user should press the back button after they successfully logged in. Keep everything the way it is and let the anti-forgery token do its job. Avoid overriding it by clearing cache, that defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: There are users who accidentally pressed or intentionally pressed the browser button just like what happened here that's why the developer reported the issue. Some users even don't have basic internet knowledge that most of them will think that the site is not working even if it's just a simple error. As developers we should handle any exceptions and provide even layman's term error message instead of technical terms

Comment: The log in page should have a button that would take them to the site if they are already authenticated. I would never bypass the security that is in place, that's my first priority as a developer.

Comment: Why not post your code here? Did you try it by yourself? Then post your solution if so.

Answer (score 0):

The login page is still cached on browser. I think no server-side approach to handle this but what you can do is don't cache the login page. Just put the code below in your Login.cshtml view just before the Title of the page is being declared.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="0">
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
 }
```